# execCommand not disabling 'Shrink To Fit' in IE8/9 - landscape orientation

Tags: css, printing, resize, internet-explorer-9, landscape

I have had this persisting issue with a print page in my site, where when I print the page using IE8 or 9, the browser resizes the page to a much smaller version.

I realized that if I disable 'Shrink To Fit' in the Page layout preferences, I no longer have this problem.  I found this code online that others have used to disable Shrink To Fit using JS:

```
if( navigator.appVersion.indexOf( "MSIE 9" ) != -1 ) { 
 document.execCommand( 'print', false, null ) ; 
} else { 
 print( ) ; 
}
```

This code does open the print dialog for me, but 'Shrink To Fit' is still enabled, and the page still prints too small.

I read online some other people saying they had problems using this fix when they switched their print layout to landscape, which is what I am asking the user to do before printing.

Does anyone know a way I can make this code work while also setting the page orientation to landscape?

Currently I am printing by simply using
window.print()
and a media=print css file.

My page size is fine in Chrome and Firefox (and IE10 as it turns out)...

Also, I have had no luck getting {@page {size: landscape} to work at all...so for now I am asking the user to manually switch to landscape in an alert window...

Comment: I am currently using yet another alert if the app detects <=IE9 ... to ask the user to un-check "Shrink To Fit"...not so great but might be enough for this one..if anyone has a better idea, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 0):

The re-size of the html page to a smaller version when printing to  is due to the width for the elements in your page and ultimately width of your html element. The browser takes in account the whole width of the page, not only the printable/visible.
In order to force the desired page size on printing add the following in your media=print CSS file:

```
html{width:1024px;}
```

where you want to substitute **1024px** with the width of your biggest printed element in the page.